# Grid-Eye Evaluation Board

Tags: atmel

I have an issue with Grid-Eye Eval Kit (Panasonic production).
I could not connect it to the PC with USB port. The PC cannot recognize it to perform the application and also COM port.
I have installed USB driver, but no reaction from PC! It seems to have a bootloader on the MCU but I dont know how to solve it.
Anybody has solution for this problem ?
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my issue, go to this address and download the firmware and download built file into MCU (SAMD21G18A) by microchip studio developer IDE.

https://mediap.industry.panasonic.eu/assets/custom-upload/Components/Sensors/Industrial%20Sensors/Infrared%20Array%20Sensor%20Grid-EYE/GridEye_Evaluation_Kit_Firmware.zip